# Bitmap vs other format drawing for control (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, paint

I'm currently working on a C# w/ .NET framework 3.5 project. I have made multiple custom controls (button and checkbox).

I'm working on a windows embedded standard 7 so I must make the interface as light as possible.

All the controls have a specific image loaded from ressources file. Is the image format (jpg/bmp/png etc.) change the drawing speed of the control? Or is it prepared at the compilation time so I don't have to worry about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't transform the image format.

So if you want speed, use BMP, it is uncompressed and can be transferred to the video memory the fastest.

There are a few exeptions:

1) You have JPG decoding in your graphics pipeline.

2) The memory pipeline between the storage and the graphics memory is really slow (compared to the CPU) (Thats why we use JPG on the web :).

Comment: Does it mean that each time a image must be painted the program decompress the format if it's not a bmp (e.g. png/jpg)?

Comment: @Mr.Alexz: good question and hard to answer. It really depends on how you code things. At normal use, images are cached in video mem for fast access. That's actually why a lot of people are having problems with showing images in long lists on mobile devices: "Out of memory", due to this caching.